# How save sorting in dataTable in shiny? (R language)

Tags: r, datatable, frontend, shiny

I have table on page with possible sorting in columns, by after I reload data table isn't sorted again, here the code:

```
    library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Return the requested dataset
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset2,
           "[,...]" = diamonds,
           "[10:30,...]" = diamonds,
           "[31:50,...]" = diamonds)
  })

  #"[,...]" = diamonds[,],
  #"[10:30,...]" = diamonds[10:30,],
  #"[31:50,...]" = diamonds[31:50,])

  # Show the first "n" observations
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput())
  })

  # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    library(ggplot2)
    datasetInput()[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  }, options = list(stateSave = TRUE))

})
```

Comment: after page reload save is saving, but after change select value it isn't.

Comment: I mean sorting is saving after page reload